# proxy cache nginx streaming parameters

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as proxy cache (edge server) in streaming environement (live hls) but I'm not sure about two parameters present since long time.

I cache playlist (m3u8) for 1 second and chunk (ts) for 120 seconds. It works pretty well just sometimes I get a 200 response from playlist while there is no stream yet and this response has in header => `cache-status: updating` then after I get well a 404 (issue is random) ; I'm still investigating on origin side.

> proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

and

> proxy_cache_use_stale updating;

What's your opinion ? Do I need to let them ?

Thanks